# Writing to file with ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: vb6, character-encoding

I have some vb6 code that is stubbornly writing to Windows-1252.

```
  Open fileName For Binary Access Write As #fileNo
  Put #fileNo, , contents
  Close #fileNo
```

I managed to make it write to UTF-16 (LE) by doing this;

```
contents = ChrW$(&HFEFF&) & contents
```

Is there any way I could easily make it write to ISO-8859-1? Examples/suggestions would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Putting a fake BOM at the beginning doens't magically make it UTF-16. You'd also need to change the data writing to output the raw unicode data.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and it is a dirty fix =]

Comment: it's not a fix, its a straight out lie. The text will still be encoded as the local character set unless you write out data (not a string)

Comment: @Deanna: Are you sure about that? I can't find any documentation that explains this, but presumably the concatenation of a wide-character string with a regular string is a wide-character string (with the regular string's characters being promoted/widened). If `Put` is happily writing out `x{FEFF}` as `\xFF\xFE` (little-endian UTF-16), as the question seems to imply, then that suggests that (for example) `\x20` would be written out as `\x20\x00`. In other words, I'm *guessing* that it's writing out genuine UTF-16LE, not just ASCII prepended with a UTF-16LE BOM.

Comment: @ruakh: Yes. VB strings are ALWAYS unicode internally, but are converted to the local character set when going outside of its control, e.g. to a file, or the API. With `content` being a string (a byte array fails with type mismatch) containing `wibble`, the code above writes `77 69 62 62 6C 65`. Adding the fake BOM to the string, just results in it preprending a `3F` to the start of the binary data.

Comment: [If you want to discuss further...](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5468/room-for-deanna-and-ruakh)

Comment: @Deanna: You're saying that the BOM gets converted to an ASCII question mark. But if that's the case -- if it's not even successfully writing a BOM, let alone writing the rest of the file as UTF-16 -- then how come OP says that (s)he "managed to make it write to UTF-16 (LE)"?

Comment: @ruakh: Exactly. Who knows what they got as they seem to be very vague on details. It will correctly be UTF-16 (I think) if content was a byte array but then they can't do string concatenation on it.

Comment: @Deanna: I know you were simplifying, but those ANSI conversions have little to do with anything going out of VB's control.  They are performed intentionally, and primarily so that VB6 could transition to Unicode while maintaining compatibility with Win9x and old data files.  Sadly we never got a VB7 to help transition further, but only the flimsy FSO as a stopgap bone tossed to us.

Comment: Interesting discussion, thanks to all of you. I learned something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your files are not huge then ADO can come to the rescue for quick and dirty handling of odd encodings.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Main()
    Const contents As String = "Hello World.  (4 × 6) ÷ 8 = 3 €€€ ƒƒƒ"
    Dim Stm As ADODB.Stream

    Set Stm = New ADODB.Stream
    With Stm
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "iso-8859-1"
        .LineSeparator = adLF
        .WriteText contents, adWriteLine
        .SaveToFile "ISO-8859-1.txt", adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close

        .Open
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "windows-1252"
        .LineSeparator = adCRLF
        .WriteText contents, adWriteLine
        .SaveToFile "Windows-1252.txt", adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know a BOM only applies to Unicode, and if you want ISO-8859-1 then a BOM makes no sense.

Comment: I should point out the control over line-ends too.  You can choose among CR, LF, and CRLF.  You can even use this to read encoded files.

Answer (score 3):

Windows-1252 is essentially a superset of ISO-8859-1; just write your data as Windows-1522, and don't use any of the Windows-1252 characters that aren't also ISO-8859-1 characters.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, however it wasn't accepted as a solution by my counterparts. Any other thoughts?

Comment: How are your counterparts determining the file encoding? That is, how are they deciding that your output-file is "Windows-1252" rather than the "ISO-8859-1" that they want? (Is it possible that you're misunderstanding their problem?)

Comment: They have some old software with which they claim they had specific problems with Windows-1252. That's about all I know, and they are refusing to budge on it. I'm thinking of just writing a simple c# tool to do the conversion after the first writing. Silly, but maybe not sillier than spending much time figuring out a vb6 solution.

Comment: In that case, just tell them you're sending them ISO-8859-1. That's the truth. (But just to be on the safe side, you should write a simple C# tool to make sure that it is, in fact, ISO-8859-1!)

Answer (score 3):

VB6 character output is encoded in the default machine code page for non-Unicode programs.

- If you can manage to set your machine code page to 28591, which is the [Windows code page for iso-8859-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756.aspx), then you can be absolutely sure that your output will be iso-8859-1
- Alternatively just avoid the characters where Windows 1252 differs from ISO-8859-1. Wikipedia says that is 128 to 159. You could detect them and substitute with question marks or throw an error.

Comment: Questions marks work for some things like the Euro sign (€) but in some cases translation is expected, e.g. ƒ to f.