# Encoding of Text Files in VB 6.0

Tags: encoding, vb6, filestream

I have huge external files with the "ANSI" and "UCS-2 Little Endian" encoding formats.

Now I want to change the file encoding format into UTF-8 using Visual Basic 6.0. I don't want to modify the original file; I just want to change the encoding format alone.

I have searched on the web; but can't understand the VB code, and have no idea how to do it.

I would also like to be able to read lines one at a time from UTF-8 encoded files.

Comment: If you don't understand what's encoding about read this [excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). I can't help you with VB6, but here are some similar SO questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327984/writing-to-file-with-iso-8859-1-encoding), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182102/vb6-vbscript-change-file-encoding-to-ansii).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NOTE. This answer has been extensively expanded to fit in with the edited question, which in turn was due to [Visual Basic 6 and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473252/visual-basic-6-and-utf-8)

The following code wraps up converting ANSI, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoded strings from a file to UTF-8 strings, in VB6. You have to load in the entire file and output it. Note that if it was truly generic, the LineInputUTF8() method would be LineInput(), and require a code page.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long _
) As Long

Public Const CP_ACP        As Long = 0          ' Default ANSI code page.
Public Const CP_UTF8       As Long = 65001      ' UTF8.
Public Const CP_UTF16_LE   As Long = 1200       ' UTF16 - little endian.
Public Const CP_UTF16_BE   As Long = 1201       ' UTF16 - big endian.
Public Const CP_UTF32_LE   As Long = 12000      ' UTF32 - little endian.
Public Const CP_UTF32_BE   As Long = 12001      ' UTF32 - big endian.

' Purpose:  Heuristic to determine whether bytes in a file are UTF-8.
Private Function FileBytesAreUTF8(ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer) As Boolean

    Const knSampleByteSize          As Long = 2048
    Dim nLof                        As Long
    Dim nByteCount                  As Long
    Dim nByteIndex                  As Long
    Dim nCharExtraByteCount         As Long
    Dim bytValue                    As Byte

    ' We look at the first <knSampleByteSize> bytes of the file. However, if the file is smaller, we will have to
    ' use the smaller size.
    nLof = LOF(the_iFileNo)
    If nLof < knSampleByteSize Then
        nByteCount = nLof
    Else
        nByteCount = knSampleByteSize
    End If

    ' Go to the start of the file.
    Seek #the_iFileNo, 1

    For nByteIndex = 1 To nByteCount

        Get #the_iFileNo, , bytValue

        ' If the character we are processing has bytes beyond 1, then we are onto the next character.
        If nCharExtraByteCount = 0 Then
            '
            ' The UTF-8 specification says that the first byte of a character has masking bits which indicate how many bytes follow.
            '
            ' See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description
            '
            ' Bytes in
            ' sequence   Byte 1   Byte 2   Byte 3   Byte 4
            ' 1          0xxxxxxx
            ' 2          110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
            ' 3          1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
            ' 4          11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
            '
            If (bytValue And &H80) = &H0 Then
                nCharExtraByteCount = 0
            ElseIf (bytValue And &HE0) = &HC0 Then
                nCharExtraByteCount = 1
            ElseIf (bytValue And &HF0) = &HE0 Then
                nCharExtraByteCount = 2
            ElseIf (bytValue And &HF8) = &HF0 Then
                nCharExtraByteCount = 3
            Else
                ' If none of these masks were matched, then this can't be a UTF-8 character.
                FileBytesAreUTF8 = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            ' All following bytes must be masked as in the table above.
            If (bytValue And &HC0) = &H80 Then
                nCharExtraByteCount = nCharExtraByteCount - 1
                If nCharExtraByteCount = 0 Then
                    FileBytesAreUTF8 = True
                End If
            Else
                ' Not a UTF8 character.
                FileBytesAreUTF8 = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If

    Next nByteIndex

End Function

' Purpose:  Take a string whose bytes are in the byte array <the_abytCPString>, with code page <the_nCodePage>, convert to a VB string.
Private Function FromCPString(ByRef the_abytCPString() As Byte, ByVal the_nCodePage As Long) As String

    Dim sOutput                     As String
    Dim nValueLen                   As Long
    Dim nOutputCharLen              As Long

    ' If the code page says this is already compatible with the VB string, then just copy it into the string. No messing.
    If the_nCodePage = CP_UTF16_LE Then
        FromCPString = the_abytCPString()
    Else

        ' Cache the input length.
        nValueLen = UBound(the_abytCPString) - LBound(the_abytCPString) + 1

        ' See how big the output buffer will be.
        nOutputCharLen = MultiByteToWideChar(the_nCodePage, 0&, VarPtr(the_abytCPString(LBound(the_abytCPString))), nValueLen, 0&, 0&)

        ' Resize output byte array to the size of the UTF-8 string.
        sOutput = Space$(nOutputCharLen)

        ' Make this API call again, this time giving a pointer to the output byte array.
        MultiByteToWideChar the_nCodePage, 0&, VarPtr(the_abytCPString(LBound(the_abytCPString))), nValueLen, StrPtr(sOutput), nOutputCharLen

        ' Return the array.
        FromCPString = sOutput

    End If

End Function

Public Function GetContents(ByVal the_sTextFile As String, ByRef out_nCodePage As Long, Optional ByVal the_nDesiredCodePage As Long = -1, Optional ByRef out_bContainedBOM As Boolean) As String

    Dim iFileNo                     As Integer
    Dim abytFileContents()          As Byte
    Dim nDataSize                   As Long

    iFileNo = FreeFile

    OpenForInput the_sTextFile, iFileNo, out_nCodePage, the_nDesiredCodePage, out_bContainedBOM

    ' We want to read the entire contents of the file (not including any BOM value).
    ' After calling OpenForInput(), the file pointer should be positioned after any BOM.
    ' So size file contents buffer to <file size> - <current position> + 1.
    nDataSize = LOF(iFileNo) - Seek(iFileNo) + 1
    ReDim abytFileContents(1 To nDataSize)
    Get #iFileNo, , abytFileContents()

    Close iFileNo

    ' Now we must convert this to UTF-8. But we have to first convert to the Windows NT standard UTF-16 LE.
    GetContents = FromCPString(abytFileContents(), out_nCodePage)

End Function

' Purpose:  Reads up to the end of the current line of the file, repositions to the beginning of the next line, if any, and
'           outputs all characters found.
' Inputs:   the_nFileNo     The number of the file.
' Outputs:  out_sLine       The line from the current position in the file.
' Return:   True if there is more data.
Public Function LineInputUTF8(ByVal the_nFileNo As Integer, ByRef out_sLine As String) As Boolean

    Dim bytValue            As Byte
    Dim abytLine()          As Byte
    Dim nStartOfLinePos     As Long
    Dim nEndOfLinePos       As Long
    Dim nStartOfNextLine    As Long
    Dim nLineLen            As Long

    ' Save the current file position as the beginning of the line, and cache this value.
    nStartOfLinePos = Seek(the_nFileNo)

    ' Retrieves the first byte from the current position.
    Get #the_nFileNo, , bytValue

    ' Loop until the end of file is encountered.
    Do Until EOF(the_nFileNo)

        ' Check whether this byte represents a carriage return or line feed character (indicating new line).
        If bytValue = 13 Or bytValue = 10 Then
            ' By this point, the current position is *after* the CR or LF character, so to get the position of the
            ' last byte in the line, we must go back two bytes.
            nEndOfLinePos = Seek(the_nFileNo) - 2

            ' If this is a carriage return, then we must check the next character.
            If bytValue = 13 Then
                Get #the_nFileNo, , bytValue
                ' Is this a line feed?
                If bytValue = 10 Then
                ' Yes. Assume that CR-LF counts as a single NewLine. So the start of the next line should skip over the line feed.
                    nStartOfNextLine = nEndOfLinePos + 3
                Else
                ' No. The start of the next line is the current position.
                    nStartOfNextLine = nEndOfLinePos + 2
                End If
            ElseIf bytValue = 10 Then
            ' If this is a line feed, then the start of the next line is the current position.
                nStartOfNextLine = nEndOfLinePos + 2
            End If

            ' Since we have processed all the bytes in the line, exit the loop.
            Exit Do
        End If

        ' Get the next byte.
        Get #the_nFileNo, , bytValue
    Loop

    ' Check to see if there was an end of line.
    If nEndOfLinePos = 0 Then
    ' No, this is the end of the file - so use all the remaining characters.
        nLineLen = Seek(the_nFileNo) - nStartOfLinePos - 1
    Else
    ' Yes - so use all the characters up to the end of line position.
        nLineLen = nEndOfLinePos - nStartOfLinePos + 1
    End If

    ' Is this line empty?
    If nLineLen = 0 Then
    ' Yes - just return an empty string.
        out_sLine = vbNullString
    Else
    ' No - pull all the bytes from the beginning to the end of the line into a byte array, and then convert that from UTF-8 to a VB string.
        ReDim abytLine(1 To nLineLen)
        Get #the_nFileNo, nStartOfLinePos, abytLine()
        out_sLine = FromCPString(abytLine(), CP_UTF8)
    End If

    ' If there is a line afterwards, then move to the beginning of the line, and return True.
    If nStartOfNextLine > 0 Then
        Seek #the_nFileNo, nStartOfNextLine
        LineInputUTF8 = True
    End If

End Function

' Purpose:  Analogue of 'Open "fileName" For Input As #fileNo' - but also return what type of text this is via a Code Page value.
' Inputs:   the_sFileName
'           the_iFileNo
'           (the_nDesiredCodePage)  The code page that you want to use with this file.
'                                   If this value is set to the default, -1, this indicates that the code page will be ascertained from the file.
' Outputs:  out_nCodePage           There are only six valid values that are returned if <the_nDesiredCodePage> was set to -1.
'               CP_ACP        ANSI code page
'               CP_UTF8       UTF-8
'               CP_UTF16LE    UTF-16 Little Endian (VB and NT default string encoding)
'               CP_UTF16BE    UTF-16 Big Endian
'               CP_UTF32LE    UTF-32 Little Endian
'               CP_UTF32BE    UTF-32 Big Endian
'           (out_bContainedBOM)     If this was set to True, then the file started with a BOM (Byte Order Marker).
Public Sub OpenForInput(ByRef the_sFilename As String, ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer, ByRef out_nCodePage As Long, Optional ByVal the_nDesiredCodePage As Long = -1, Optional ByRef out_bContainedBOM As Boolean)

    ' Note if we want to take account of every case, we should read in the first four bytes, and check for UTF-32 low and high endian BOMs, check
    ' the first three bytes for the UTF-8 BOM, and finally check the first two bytes for UTF-16 low and hight endian BOMs.
    Dim abytBOM(1 To 4)             As Byte
    Dim nCodePage                   As Long

    ' By default, there is no BOM.
    out_bContainedBOM = False

    Open the_sFilename For Binary Access Read As #the_iFileNo

    ' We are interested in -1 (ascertain code page), and then various UTF encodings.
    Select Case the_nDesiredCodePage
    Case -1, CP_UTF8, CP_UTF16_BE, CP_UTF16_LE, CP_UTF32_BE, CP_UTF32_LE

        ' Default code page.
        nCodePage = CP_ACP

        ' Pull in the first four bytes to determine the BOM (byte order marker).
        Get #the_iFileNo, , abytBOM()

        ' The following are the BOMs for text files:
        '
        ' FF FE         UTF-16, little endian
        ' FE FF         UTF-16, big endian
        ' EF BB BF      UTF-8
        ' FF FE 00 00   UTF-32, little endian
        ' 00 00 FE FF   UTF-32, big-endian
        '
        ' Work out the code page from this information.

        Select Case abytBOM(1)
        Case &HFF
            If abytBOM(2) = &HFE Then
                If abytBOM(3) = 0 And abytBOM(4) = 0 Then
                    nCodePage = CP_UTF32_LE
                Else
                    nCodePage = CP_UTF16_LE
                End If
            End If
        Case &HFE
            If abytBOM(2) = &HFF Then
                nCodePage = CP_UTF16_BE
            End If
        Case &HEF
            If abytBOM(2) = &HBB And abytBOM(3) = &HBF Then
                nCodePage = CP_UTF8
            End If
        Case &H0
            If abytBOM(2) = &H0 And abytBOM(3) = &HFE And abytBOM(4) = &HFF Then
                nCodePage = CP_UTF32_BE
            End If
        End Select

        ' Did we match any BOMs?
        If nCodePage = CP_ACP Then
        ' No - we are still defaulting to the ANSI code page.
            ' Special check for UTF-8. The BOM is not specified in the standard for UTF-8, but according to Wikipedia (which is always right :-) ),
            ' only Microsoft includes this marker at the beginning of files.
            If FileBytesAreUTF8(the_iFileNo) Then
                out_nCodePage = CP_UTF8
            Else
                out_nCodePage = CP_ACP
            End If
        Else
        ' Yes - we have worked out the code page from the BOM.
            ' If no code page was suggested, we now return the code page we found.
            If the_nDesiredCodePage = -1 Then
                out_nCodePage = nCodePage
            End If

            ' Inform the caller that a BOM was found.
            out_bContainedBOM = True
        End If

        ' Reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file data.
        If out_bContainedBOM Then
            ' Note that if the code page found was one of the two UTF-32 values, then we are already in the correct position.
            ' Otherwise, we have to move to just after the end of the BOM.
            Select Case nCodePage
            Case CP_UTF16_BE, CP_UTF16_LE
                Seek #the_iFileNo, 3
            Case CP_UTF8
                Seek #the_iFileNo, 4
            End Select
        Else
            ' There is no BOM, so simply go the beginning of the file.
            Seek #the_iFileNo, 1
        End If

    Case Else
        out_nCodePage = the_nDesiredCodePage
    End Select

End Sub

' Purpose:  Analogue of 'Open "fileName" For Append As #fileNo'
Public Sub OpenForAppend(ByRef the_sFilename As String, ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer, Optional ByVal the_nCodePage As Long = CP_ACP, Optional ByVal the_bPrefixWithBOM As Boolean = True)

    ' Open the file and move to the end of the file.
    Open the_sFilename For Binary Access Write As #the_iFileNo
    Seek the_iFileNo, LOF(the_iFileNo) + 1

    If the_bPrefixWithBOM Then
        WriteBOM the_iFileNo, the_nCodePage
    End If

End Sub

' Purpose:  Analogue of 'Open "fileName" For Output As #fileNo'
Public Sub OpenForOutput(ByRef the_sFilename As String, ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer, Optional ByVal the_nCodePage As Long = CP_ACP, Optional ByVal the_bPrefixWithBOM As Boolean = True)

    ' Ensure we overwrite the file by deleting it ...
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill the_sFilename
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' ... before creating it.
    Open the_sFilename For Binary Access Write As #the_iFileNo

    If the_bPrefixWithBOM Then
        WriteBOM the_iFileNo, the_nCodePage
    End If

End Sub

' Purpose:  Analogue of the 'Print #fileNo, value' statement. But only one value allowed.
'           Setting <the_bAppendNewLine> = False is analagous to 'Print #fileNo, value;'.
Public Sub Print_(ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer, ByRef the_sValue As String, Optional ByVal the_nCodePage As Long = CP_ACP, Optional ByVal the_bAppendNewLine As Boolean = True)

    Const kbytNull                  As Byte = 0
    Const kbytCarriageReturn        As Byte = 13
    Const kbytNewLine               As Byte = 10

    Put #the_iFileNo, , ToCPString(the_sValue, the_nCodePage)

    If the_bAppendNewLine Then
        Select Case the_nCodePage
        Case CP_UTF16_BE
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytCarriageReturn
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNewLine
        Case CP_UTF16_LE
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytCarriageReturn
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNewLine
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
        Case CP_UTF32_BE
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytCarriageReturn
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNewLine
        Case CP_UTF32_LE
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytCarriageReturn
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNewLine
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNull
        Case Else
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytCarriageReturn
            Put #the_iFileNo, , kbytNewLine
        End Select
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub PutContents(ByRef the_sFilename As String, ByRef the_sFileContents As String, Optional ByVal the_nCodePage As Long = CP_ACP, Optional the_bPrefixWithBOM As Boolean)

    Dim iFileNo                     As Integer

    iFileNo = FreeFile
    OpenForOutput the_sFilename, iFileNo, the_nCodePage, the_bPrefixWithBOM
    Print_ iFileNo, the_sFileContents, the_nCodePage, False
    Close iFileNo

End Sub

' Purpose:  Converts a VB string (UTF-16) to UTF8 - as a binary array.
Private Function ToCPString(ByRef the_sValue As String, ByVal the_nCodePage As Long) As Byte()

    Dim abytOutput()                As Byte
    Dim nValueLen                   As Long
    Dim nOutputByteLen              As Long

    If the_nCodePage = CP_UTF16_LE Then
        ToCPString = the_sValue
    Else

        ' Cache the input length.
        nValueLen = Len(the_sValue)

        ' See how big the output buffer will be.
        nOutputByteLen = WideCharToMultiByte(the_nCodePage, 0&, StrPtr(the_sValue), nValueLen, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&)

        If nOutputByteLen > 0 Then
            ' Resize output byte array to the size of the UTF-8 string.
            ReDim abytOutput(1 To nOutputByteLen)

            ' Make this API call again, this time giving a pointer to the output byte array.
            WideCharToMultiByte the_nCodePage, 0&, StrPtr(the_sValue), nValueLen, VarPtr(abytOutput(1)), nOutputByteLen, 0&, 0&
        End If

        ' Return the array.
        ToCPString = abytOutput()

    End If

End Function

Private Sub WriteBOM(ByVal the_iFileNo As Integer, ByVal the_nCodePage As Long)

    ' FF FE         UTF-16, little endian
    ' FE FF         UTF-16, big endian
    ' EF BB BF      UTF-8
    ' FF FE 00 00   UTF-32, little endian
    ' 00 00 FE FF   UTF-32, big-endian

    Select Case the_nCodePage
    Case CP_UTF8
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HEF)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HBB)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HBF)
    Case CP_UTF16_LE
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFF)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFE)
    Case CP_UTF16_BE
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFE)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFF)
    Case CP_UTF32_LE
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFF)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFE)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&H0)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&H0)
    Case CP_UTF32_BE
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&H0)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&H0)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFE)
        Put #the_iFileNo, , CByte(&HFF)
    End Select

End Sub
```

The following code was added to a Form which had a VSFlexGrid control with Lucida Console font - purely to provide a way to display as many characters as possible:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command_Click()
    Example_ConvertFileToUTF8
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Example_IterateUTF8Lines
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Example_ReadWriteUTF8Lines
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    VSFlexGrid.ColWidth(0) = 7000!
End Sub

' Purpose:  Converts *any* pure text file (UTF16, ASCII, ANSI) to UTF8.
Private Sub Example_ConvertFileToUTF8()

    Dim nCodePage                   As Long
    Dim bContainedBOM               As Boolean
    Dim sFileContents               As String

    ' Read in contents.
    sFileContents = TextFile.GetContents("C:\MysteryEncoding.txt", nCodePage, , bContainedBOM)

    ' And then convert to UTF8.
    TextFile.PutContents "C:\output.txt", sFileContents, CP_UTF8, bContainedBOM

End Sub

' Purpose:  Iterates through each line of a UTF-8 text file, and adds it to a control which can display VB strings containing non-ANSI characters.
'           In this case, I am adding items to a FlexGrid with Font = "Lucida Console".
Private Sub Example_IterateUTF8Lines()

    Dim iFileNo             As Integer
    Dim lCodePage           As Long
    Dim sLine               As String

    iFileNo = FreeFile

    TextFile.OpenForInput "C:\UTF8.txt", iFileNo, lCodePage

    If lCodePage = CP_UTF8 Then
        Do While TextFile.LineInputUTF8(iFileNo, sLine)
            VSFlexGrid.AddItem sLine
        Loop
        VSFlexGrid.AddItem sLine
    Else
        MsgBox "This is not a UTF8 file."
    End If

    Close #iFileNo

End Sub

Private Sub Example_ReadWriteUTF8Lines()

    Dim iFileNoInput        As Integer
    Dim iFileNoOutput       As Integer
    Dim lCodePage           As Long
    Dim bBOM                As Boolean
    Dim sLine               As String

    iFileNoInput = FreeFile
    TextFile.OpenForInput "C:\UTF8.txt", iFileNoInput, lCodePage, , bBOM

    If lCodePage = CP_UTF8 Then

        iFileNoOutput = FreeFile
        TextFile.OpenForOutput "C:\output.txt", iFileNoOutput, lCodePage, bBOM

        Do While TextFile.LineInputUTF8(iFileNoInput, sLine)
            TextFile.Print_ iFileNoOutput, sLine, lCodePage
        Loop
        TextFile.Print_ iFileNoOutput, sLine, lCodePage, False

        Close #iFileNoOutput

    Else
        MsgBox "This is not a UTF8 file."
    End If

    Close #iFileNoInput

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to convert ANSI strings (by which I assume you will be storing in a byte array) to UTF-8 strings, then first convert your ANSI string to a VB string using StrConv(abytANSI, vbUnicode), and then use ToUTF8() to convert into a UTF-8 byte array.

Comment: VB6 file I/O uses ANSI files by default. If Ramesh is using standard VB6 file I/O statements, then even though the files are ANSI files, the internal strings will be normal VB6 strings (Unicode UTF-16) not ANSI strings.

Comment: I am having two external files, which type is "UCS-2 Little Endian" and "ANSI". Now i want to change these file formats to "UTF-8". Above code is opening and writing file with some string values. I dont need to add any values, just i want to change the encoding of those files...

Comment: @Ramesh - you changed your question. As a result, I have had to change my answer. Please don't change it again, otherwise we could be here forever.

Comment: Hi, Can I also use this to convert a file to CP852/IBM852 encoding, if yes  can you show me how, thanks

Comment: Just wanted to add that I don't think this works for BigEndian-ness. (The call to WideCharToMultiBute with 1201 - CP_UTF16_BE - returns 0). From what I've read, it appears that you need to reverse the Little Endian byte order yourself. Happy to be corrected!

Answer (score 0):

I have to some vb6 code to change file encoding ANSI to Encoding UTF-8.

```
'--- start function for convert to UTF-8

Private Function OpenAppendUTF8(ByVal FileName As String) As Integer
    OpenAppendUTF8 = FreeFile(0)
    Open FileName For Binary Access Write As #OpenAppendUTF8
    Seek #OpenAppendUTF8, LOF(OpenAppendUTF8) + 1
End Function

Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)
   If Dir$(FileToDelete) = "" Then  'See above
   Else
      SetAttr FileToDelete, vbNormal
      Kill FileToDelete
   End If
End Sub
'-

Private Sub WriteUTF8( _
    ByVal FNum As Integer, _
    ByVal Text As String, _
    Optional ByVal NL As Boolean)

    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim UTF8() As Byte

    If NL Then Text = Text & vbNewLine
    lngResult = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(Text), Len(Text), _
                                    0, 0, 0, 0)
    If lngResult > 0 Then
        ReDim UTF8(lngResult - 1)
        WideCharToMultiByte CP_UTF8, 0, StrPtr(Text), Len(Text), _
                            VarPtr(UTF8(0)), lngResult, 0, 0
        Put #FNum, , UTF8
    End If
End Sub
'------- end function for convert to UTF-8
'>>> coding 
             Dim ReadString As String
             Dim writeString As String
             Dim txtNotepad As String
             Dim FileNumber As Integer
             Dim UTF8 As String
             Dim strsql  As String
             Dim iloop As Integer
             FileNumber = FreeFile(1)                
                '--- if you need to delete file first.
                DeleteFile App.Path & "\PRB\fieldRules.txt"
                '---
                FileNumber = OpenAppendUTF8(App.Path & "\PRB\fieldRules.txt")
                iloop = 1
                Do While iloop > 0
                     iloop = InStr(1, txtNotepad, "\n")
                     '  "\n" for end of line 

                     If iloop <= 5 Then
                        iloop = 0
                     Else
                        'writeString = Mid(txtNotepad, 1, iloop - 1)
                        'Print #FileNumber, writeString
                        WriteUTF8 FileNumber, Mid(txtNotepad, 1, iloop - 1), True
                        txtNotepad = Mid(txtNotepad, iloop + 3, 9999)
                     End If
                Loop
                Close #FileNumber
<<<< end code
```