# Converting a byte array with system locale set to Japanese in VB6

Tags: vb6, locale, strconv

In my legacy VB6 application I'm receiving a zip file as a byte array from a webservice. This byte array is converted to a string using the StrConv function and stored on the file system.

```
Dim arr() As Byte
Dim sUnicode as String

nFile = FreeFile
arr = objHTTP.responseBody

sUnicode = StrConv(arr, vbUnicode)

Open sFile For Output As #nFile
Print #nFile, sUnicode
Close #nFile
```

So far so good, this has worked correctly for over a decade.
Now the application is used in Japan as well and the code above leads to a corrupt zip file.

I already found out that the issue is related to the Japanese system locale on the target system.

I tried passing the locale id 1033 to the StrConv function

```
StrConv(arr, vbUnicode, 1033)
```

Next I tried implementing the solution as descibed by this link

[Encoding of Text Files in VB 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809081/encoding-of-text-files-in-vb-6-0)

Also I tried changing the system locale using the 'SetLocaleInfo' api-call.

None of the attempts have lead to a valid zip file on a OS with the system locale set to Japanese.

Does anybody know how to get a working solution?

Thanks in advance,

Jos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid the string conversion entirely.  Try something like this:

```
Dim arr() As Byte

nFile = FreeFile
arr = objHTTP.responseBody

Open sFile For Binary As #nFile
Put #nFile, , arr
Close #nFile
```

This writes the contents of your array directly to the file.

Comment: +1 Some byte sequences will not be valid strings in the Japanese encoding. You must avoid the use of strings entirely.